# Несколько элементов select и результат выбранных параметров

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер, я не знаю как сделать чтобы было несколько элементов `select` и, в зависимости от выбора в предыдущем селекте, должны меняться доступные варианты в следующем и в результате подтягиваться информация в зависимости от выбранной комбинации параметров.
Пример: есть элемент селект в котором храниться модель машины (форд, вольво, ауди), следующий селект марки каждых моделей и в результате появляется  информация с характеристиками машины которую выбрал.

```html
<SELECT NAME="Marka">
  <OPTION VALUE=Вольво>Вольво</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=Ауди>Ауди</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=Форд>Форд</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<SELECT NAME="Model">
  <OPTION VALUE=S60>S60</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=S60>S80</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=S100>S100</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=A4>A4</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=A6>A6</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=A8>A8</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=B-Max>B-Max</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=C-Max>C-Max</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=Fiesta 5-ти дверная>Fiesta 5-ти дверная</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Проблема в том не знаю как например при выборе марки вольво показывались только модели этой модели, когда выбрал модель появлялось бы поле с характеристикой этой модели, мне бы хотя бы только один пример как это оформляется.

Comment: Укажите Ваш код и/или наработки по достижению желаемого. Иначе за Вас вряд ли кто-то будет делать что-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я в машинах не разбираюсь совсем, поэтому написал всякую фигню в массив.
Как-то так, наверное:

```js
(function(){
 var cars = {
   'audi': {
     'x7': [
       'Audi X7',
       'Что-то тЫкс седьмое.'
     ],
     't800': [
       'Audi T-800',
       'Терминатор!'
     ]
   },
   'ford': {
     'harrison': [
       'Ford Harrison',
       'Микс Хана Соло и Индианы Джонса'
     ],
     'henry': [
       'Ford Henry',
       'Созидатель бренда'
     ]
   }
 }

 function changeBrand(){
   var brand = document.querySelector('#brand');
   var wrTypeBrand = document.querySelector('#wrapperTypeBrand');
   var str = '<select id="typeBrand">';
   var type = cars[brand.value];
   for(var e in type)
     str += '<option value="' + e + '">' + type[e][0] + '</option>';
   str += '</select>';
   wrTypeBrand.innerHTML = str;
   setTimeout(function(){
     changeTypeBrand();
     document.querySelector('#typeBrand').addEventListener('change', changeTypeBrand);
   }, 0);
 }
  
 function changeTypeBrand(){
   var brand = document.querySelector('#brand').value;
   var type = document.querySelector('#typeBrand').value;
   var desc = document.querySelector('#desc');

   desc.innerHTML = cars[brand][type][1];
 }

 function load(){
   changeBrand();
   document.querySelector('#brand').addEventListener('change', changeBrand);
 }

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load);
})();
```

```html
<select id='brand'>
  <option value='audi'>Audi</option>
  <option value='ford'>Ford</option>
</select>
<div id='wrapperTypeBrand'></div>
<div id='wrapperDesc'>
  <h2>Описание:</h2>
  <div id='desc'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! А такой еще вопрос если таких показателей не несколько как в этом примере, а пару десятков то принцип такой же?

Comment: @darthael, В общем и целом - да: хранение данных в объекте и на его основе генерировать дальнейшие шаги.
Пример писался для... примера, так что до рабочего его нужно переписать, главное концепцию донёс :)

Answer (score 1):

ну как-то так:

```js
$('select[name=Marka]').change(function() {
  $('select[name=Model] option').hide();
  $('select[name=Model] option.' + $('select[name=Marka]').val()).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<SELECT NAME="Marka">
  <OPTION VALUE=1 class="default">выберите модель</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="v">Вольво</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="a">Ауди</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE="f">Форд</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<SELECT NAME="Model">
  <OPTION VALUE=1 class="default">выберите модель</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=1 class="v">S60</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=2 class="v">S80</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=3 class="v">S100</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=4 class="a">A4</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=5 class="a">A6</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=6 class="a">A8</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=7 class="f">B-Max</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=8 class="f">C-Max</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=9 class="f">Fiesta 5-ти дверная</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJbdgO

Использован jQuery для простоты выборки.

Comment: Используйте кнопку "вставить фрагмент" для добавления кода. Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным, ссылки на JSFiddle и подобные ресурсы могут служить только дополнением.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!